# android programming : I want to have a specific folder like whatsapp have to store its app file?

Tags: android

I want to have a folder in my device storage to store csv files as per the requirement of my app but i m not able to create a folder in my internal storage that is visible to user through file explorer.

I have tried many codes but those only created folders on those devices having sd card not like whatsapp have in internal storage
So how can i create a folder of my app name in internal storage and visible to a

Answer (score 0):

To create folder in internal storage you can do something like this,

```
File mydir = context.getDir("mydir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Creating an internal dir;
File fileWithinMyDir = new File(mydir, "myfile"); //Getting a file within the dir.
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileWithinMyDir); //Use the stream as usual to write into the file.
```

Don't forget to include permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: i have tried this . Bt it is not creating a directory visible to me in my mobile phone in file explorer

Answer (score 0):

```
File newDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myAppName");
newDir.mkdirs();
```

This will be in the internal storage on any modern Android device.
You need

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and also have the user grant the runtime permission on Android 6.0+ https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: i have done same but it is not creating a visible folder in my phone not having sd card  if i run the app in phone having sd card it creates directory

Comment: It will be in 'internal storage'. Are you sure you have the runtime permission? What is the return result of mkdirs()?

Comment: run time permission means i have added the above permission in manifest

Comment: No, it doesn't.